# Botium-Box - Need to add more than 1 response for an utterance like switch case statement logic

Tags: bots, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

My botium scripts fails when I get a different response for the same
utterance

1.While recording the test case

```
My Utterance : Open Test

Alexa Response : Hello test ,How are you
```

2.Now I save it as a test case through quick start I run the same

```
Now 

My Utterance : Open Test

Expected Alexa Response : Hello test ,How are you 

Actual Alexa Response : Hello test,How are finding alexa skill
```

**My action item to achieve**

I have an utterance for which i can have 2 or 3 different response .If i get any one of the three then i must be able to proceed with the test script in Botium-Box

Currently

> Since this is my Alexa skills behaviour .I want to know how to go with
>   this . Like switch case statement do we have an inbuilt way to handle
>   this in Botium Box

Answer (score 0):

The Botium concept to do this is to split the test cases in *convos* and *utterances* - see [here](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-2-writing-chatbot-tests-8726204c8da6) for an introduction, but it is easy to understand:
Instead of a single utterance, multiple utterances are allowed.

When saving the conversation from the live chat as test case, enable the *Split bot messages to Convo and Utterances* switch (new in Botium Box 1.7)

[image: Save conversations as Test Case]

Botium now generates the test case with

- one convo file
- one utterances file for each *#bot* conversation step

[image: test script list]

The convo file now contains a reference to the utterance for each *#bot* conversation step:

```
MyTestCase

#me
Hi

#bot default
MYTESTCASE_BOT_1

#me
thanks

#bot default
MYTESTCASE_BOT_2
```

In the utterances file, you can now add all the possible answers of your bot for each conversation step:

```
MYTESTCASE_BOT_1
You said: Hi
Another response
And one more
```

Additional notes:

- You can reuse the utterances files in several convos
- You should invest some thoughts in a good naming concept
- You can use the utterances files in the *#me* section as well to present multiple user inputs to the chatbot for the same conversation structure

Comment: Thanks will get back to you with my results .

Comment: Works fine created the convo file with 2 response from alexa and it worked fine .Is there any assertion logic like jasmine assertions like tocontain or tomatch .Which searches for a partial or extact response match in Botium box

Comment: There is a capability to configure this: https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE

Comment: Ok i'll look into this